# How can I work with Chrome browser's cookies with Selenium Webdriver in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, cookies, webdriver

If I open my Chrome browser, it has all of the cookies from pages, what I used. I'd like to enable this cookies in ChromeDriver. So if I open for example facebook.com, I don't want to enter my username and my password, if I did that earlier.
Anyway, I want webdriver to use my cookies from my PC. 
or
How can I get all of the cookies from chrome's folder, to add to the webdriver? Theoretically I can add cookies to webdriver.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a new instance from ChromeOptions, and add the following argument:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments(@"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\your username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
```

after that, you shold add this options instance to your ChromeDriver, or iWebDriver, and of course it works with FirefixDriver, and so on...

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverPath, options);
```

So you can set, that your driver get data from your browser's User Data folder. Theoretically it works with every browser driver, just you have to search your browser's data folder.

Comment: KINGGGGGGGGGGG!